# How to wipe HDD with windows install

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot

I have a two drive system, one HDD, one SSD. The HDD has windows installed, as well as the SSD. My goal is to run Windows from the SSD, and use the HDD as storage.

With both drives attached (SATA), I *can* interrupt the startup and tell the computer to boot from the SSD. This seems to work, but then before we get to Windows, the computer "fails" and stops outputting to the monitor. If I unplug the HDD, it boots normally.

I've removed all the media I need from the HDD, I just need to wipe/reformat it. I'm tempted to start the computer, then hot-swap the HDD in as it's running, but I'm a bit nervous to cause some corruption in either disk.

Comment: The safest way is to remove the hard drive, then make sure Windows on the SSD is starting and working properly.  Put the HDD in a carrier and format it

Comment: Always backup your data before any OS movement or disk exchange!

Comment: Sounds like the EFI partition is on the HDD instead of the SSD. It’s unclear what “hot swapping” the HDD would do exactly

Comment: Normally it isn't really dangerous (to the machine) to hotplug an HDD. It's just that hotplugging isn't mandated to be an always-on feature in SATA, meaning that your BIOS/UEFI setting might have setting option that enables/disables the ability. (When it is disabled, the drive won't get detected if hotplugged. Often it is a per-port setting, btw.) Also, "fails" you mentioned is vague, so I can't tell for sure if your HDD (or PSU) is problematic in any aspect.

Comment: If your can boot to Windows with only the SSD connected, it's unlikely that the EFI system partition is on the HDD. (Well, unless it was some old MBR installation that was originally set up for BIOS/legacy booting and has been relying on the ESP on the HDD for EFI booting.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the HDD was your boot disk before you got the SSD,
so I suggest doing the following.

- Prepare a USB with
  [Windows boot media](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2376-create-bootable-usb-flash-drive-install-windows-10-a.html)
- Shutdown the computer
- Disconnect the HDD
- Execute [Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html)
- Reconnect the HDD and reformat it
  (being careful to format the right disk)
- The job is done - the SSD is now your only boot device.

Take careful backup of your data before starting the above.

Answer (score 1):

I think @harrymc 's advice is good, however this is what worked for me:

1. I poked around the bios and turned on SATA hot swap (I had to kind of guess which SATA slot the HDD would be in).
2. I unplugged the HDD, and booted from the SSD.
3. I plugged in the HDD after boot, then used Disk Manager to reformat.

Comment: My advice was aimed at keeping you safe. Your cloning of the HDD to the SSD was done correctly, so you didn't need these safety measures. Enjoy.